# Sveltekit Post Request Endpoint

Tags: sveltekit

I'm trying to do a simple post request, but running into some problems and ${ question }, ${ answer } is undefined when the sql is executed in the sql....  Any suggestions?

**+page.svelte**

```
async function add(context: string, answer: string) {
    console.log("cON")
    console.log(context)
    const response = await fetch('/api/searches/add', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({question,  answer }),
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
    } 
    
);
}
```

**api/searches/add/+server.ts**

```
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import {json} from "@sveltejs/kit";
import sql from '../../../../db';
 
export type CasinoAiSearch = {
    name: string,
    slug: string,
    question: string,
    answer: string,
    approved: boolean,
    order: number,
};


/** @type {import('./$types').RequestHandler} */
export async function POST({ request }) {
console.log("REQ");
const { question, answer } = await request.json()


let test = await sql`
    insert into users
    (name, slug, question, answer, approved, order )
    values
    ('name', 'slug', ${ question }, ${ answer }, 0, 0)
    returning name, slug, question, answer, approved, order
    `
  
    if (test) {
        return json(test)
        
      }
    
      throw error(404, 'Not found');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So you send `{ question, answer }` so you will get just that in the endpoint, *not* `{ a, b }`. Either side has to change the names of the properties, or you need to remap on destructuring, e.g.

```js
// `a` and `b` are trash variable names,
// so I don't know which is supposed to be which
const { question: a, answer: b } = await request.json();
```

Please don't use `a`/`b`...

Comment: good point, I edited it... But still undefined

Comment: Then maybe something is wrong with your SQL function, where is that from anyway?

Comment: Are the values defined *outside* the `sql\`...\``?